# How to send the nested json with the updated value?

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following json. If i change any field of this json, i have pass the whole json with updated value using jquery.

```
{
    "processDefId": "xyz",
    "name": "name",
    "sla": "10",
    "hasChild": true,
    "child": [
        {
            "activityDefId": "siteSurveyDef",
            "activityName": "Site Survey",
            "isMandatory": "true",
            "isOptional": "false",
            "sla": "10",
            "sequence": "1",
            "hasChild": true,
            "child": [
                {
                    "activityDefId": "Begin",
                    "activityName": "Begin",
                    "isMandatory": "true",
                    "isOptional": "false",
                    "sla": "10",
                    "sequence": "1",
                    "hasChild": true
                },
                {
                    "activityDefId": "Site Survey2",
                    "activityName": "Site Survey2",
                    "isMandatory": "true",
                    "isOptional": "false",
                    "sla": "10",
                    "sequence": "1",
                    "hasChild": true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "activityDefId": "siteSurvey",
            "activityName": "Procurement",
            "isMandatory": "true",
            "isOptional": "false",
            "sla": "10",
            "sequence": "1",
            "hasChild": true,
            "child": [
                {
                    "activityDefId": "Begin",
                    "activityName": "Begin"
                },
                {
                    "activityDefId": "Site Survey",
                    "activityName": "Site Survey3",
                    "isMandatory": "true",
                    "isOptional": "false",
                    "sla": "10",
                    "sequence": "1",
                    "hasChild": true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "activityDefId": "siteSurvey",
            "activityName": "Provisioning",
            "isMandatory": "true",
            "isOptional": "false",
            "sla": "10",
            "sequence": "1",
            "hasChild": true,
            "child": [
                {
                    "activityDefId": "Begin",
                    "activityName": "Begin"
                },
                {
                    "activityDefId": "Site Survey",
                    "activityName": "Site Survey4",
                    "isMandatory": "true",
                    "isOptional": "false",
                    "sla": "10",
                    "sequence": "1",
                    "hasChild": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Not getting idea how to do? Any anyone help?

Comment: what value you want to update ?

Comment: i have to update the value like: sla, isMandatory, isOptional in any part of json

Comment: So you mean to say these 3 are the only dynamic fields in your JSON and you want to replace values for these keys only. Correct me in case I'm wrong.

Comment: yes.These fields should be dynamically changed in any part of json and while returning need to send the same original json with the updated value.

Comment: can you provide an example illustrating your expected output.

Comment: I will have form to change the value of sla, isMandatory etc. If i change sla=20 in first child, then the expected json should be as same as above only with the changed value in first child with "sla":"20"

Comment: So you want to update the value "sla":"20" in all the occurrences irrespective of their position in the hierarchy.

Comment: wherever it is changed, i have to send the json with updated value in original json in their particular position.